# Payasso in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ionos

I am helping an association with their website. They use wordpress ionos. I need to add payasso to GiveWP for donation. But, in passerels suggestions, it does exist. I found paypal etc, but not what I need.Can someone help me and explain how to add it.

Comment: What is passerels suggestions?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for helping, here is the list of gateway suggestions :                
 BITPAY DONATIONS,


STRIPE GATEWAY,

AUTHORIZE.NET GATEWAY,


MOLLIE PAYMENT GATEWAY,


IATS PAYMENT SOLUTIONS,


2CHECKOUT GATEWAY,

GOCARDLESS GATEWAY,


BRAINTREE GATEWAY,


CCAVENUE GATEWAY,

SQUARE GATEWAY,


PAYUMONEY GATEWAY,


PAYFAST,


MONERIS GATEWAY,


PAYTM GATEWAY,

RAZORPAY GATEWAY,


AMERICLOUD PAYMENTS,


PAYMILL GATEWAY,


SOFORT,

Comment: It seems that Pay Asso cannot be integrated into a website. It consists of a link to a page that you can create at Crédit Mutuel. Your visitors click a link, then go to this web page, do their payments, after which they can probably be directed back to your own website. If you need it integrated, the only option I can thinks of is having the Pay Asso page to load in an iframe. This should be thoroughly tested though because ther are constraints in using an iframe.

Comment: So, as far as I can see, the only “integration” would be simply add a link to your own Pay Asso page with the text “click here to pay by Pay Asso”.

Comment: My advice would be to check with Crédit Mutuel and ask them if they have options for integration. Since you want to add Pay Asso, you probably already have a subscription with them, so that should make it easy to start a support question throught their support system.

Comment: I confirm, the association has a link. OKay, thank you for the idea. I appreciate your help